# DATAGRID - Oracle date attribute

Tags: oracle, datagrid

I have a problem about the visualization of all the attribute type "date" only in ORACLE DB. As in the image, the same date value, if I use a formatter the result is true, instead if show the column with standard output I see a false result.

[image]

Comment: what is the type of the column?

Comment: Which client and version are you running this in? And what is `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and other related formatting set to in your session (query `nls_session_parameters`, or check the preferences)? There seems to be a time zone adjustment going on, which could be OK e.g. if the column is timestamp with local time zone, but even so something is clearly gong wrong...

Comment: The column is a DATE type of Oracle. I'm using ojdbc14.jar

Comment: Why such an old version; and what version is the database? This could be a problem with an unsupported combination. Also [possibly related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42934682/266304), as it looks like the date is being treated as a timestamp and being truncated to midnight (and losing 2 hours from local time zone...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem was the old version of jdbc driver. We have a old oracle db (9) and for this we're using ojdbc14. But now we tried with ojdbc6.jar version 11.1.0.7.0 and it's run. Thanks